# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor when deploying Java EE 7 app on GlassFish 4.1

Tags: glassfish, cdi, hibernate-validator, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

Recently, when deploying my application to the GlassFish 4.1 test server, I got the following exception:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
```

Local deployment on the same application server version worked as expected. Both my local environment and the test server use java8 release 31.

The full stacktrace of the exception:

```
Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:962)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.markAllContainersAsStarted(EjbApplication.java:140)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)   
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.buildEjbInterceptorChain(InterceptorManager.java:431)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.<init>(InterceptorManager.java:131)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeInterceptorManager(BaseContainer.java:3396)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:950)
        ... 67 more
]]

[2015-02-26T11:05:11.836+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1424945111836] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing   
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:962)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.markAllContainersAsStarted(EjbApplication.java:140)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)   
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.buildEjbInterceptorChain(InterceptorManager.java:431)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.<init>(InterceptorManager.java:131)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeInterceptorManager(BaseContainer.java:3396)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:950)
        ... 67 more
```

I explicitly enabled CDI by defining a beans.xml file in my WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

Jars packaged in the war:

```
    10133  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar
    33403  2014-10-14 13:44   WEB-INF/lib/casablanca-1.0.10.jar
   104615  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/maven-project-2.0.jar
    78761  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/maven-artifact-2.0.jar
   300845  2014-10-29 11:31   WEB-INF/lib/jsoup-1.8.1.jar
    51560  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-5.jar
   591683  2015-01-27 11:40   WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-2.0.jar
   160291  2013-11-20 13:15   WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.1.1.Final.jar
   100884  2013-11-20 13:15   WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
    66440  2015-02-17 11:13   WEB-INF/lib/liquibase-maven-plugin-3.1.1.jar
    30408  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/maven-profile-2.0.jar
    50628  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.jar
   195436  2013-11-27 23:29   WEB-INF/lib/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-8.jar
  2693611  2014-10-21 09:09   WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.1.jar
   273449  2013-11-29 12:44   WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
  1265562  2014-12-17 12:15   WEB-INF/lib/liquibase-core-3.1.1.jar
    78476  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/maven-model-2.0.jar
   480632  2015-02-05 12:13   WEB-INF/lib/facebook4j-core-2.2.2.jar
    20655  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.jar
    37516  2013-11-27 23:28   WEB-INF/lib/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar
   163803  2013-05-26 19:39   WEB-INF/lib/plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
```

I tried to copy the whole test server locally, and my war sucessfully deployed on it. I also attempted to copy my local glassfish on the server, and then deployment fails.

Using -verbose:class jvm option, I noticed the class in question is loaded exactly once from the `glassfish/modules/bean-validator-cdi.jar` package, both on the working local server and on the failing remote server. This package is exactly the same on both side.

Im now trying to reduce code diff between the last jar that deploys correctly and the current version. Between these versions, diff to the pom only include removed commons- libraries. Diff to web.xml only include removed Primefaces fileuplaod filter.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you have any Hibernate Validator jars in your web archive? Are you sure that all Validators classes (the cdi related as well as the actual engine classes) are only available via jar files in the modules directory?

Comment: I added the packaged jar in the description. To my knowledge, the Validator classes are only available via the glassfish module jars (only mysql-connector and a custom osgi login module are present in the domain lib folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the cause of this issue.

Edit:
This is caused by this bug: https://github.com/javaee/hk2/issues/277

Replacing bean-validator.jar and bean-validator-cdi.jar in the glassfish modules directory by the 2.4-b06 versions (org.glassfish.hk2.external group) solves the issue.

---

Original post:

It was a `@javax.validation.constraint.NotNull` annotation on a method parameter in a `@Stateless` bean.
I have no idea how it could have caused deployment error, but it solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This probably saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some subtle class loading difference. a relatively easy way to find differences is to run both working and non-working servers with

```
java -verbose:class
```

and compare the output. If the servers are identical there should be relatively few differences. I've found this verbose option very useful in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Hovever, I noticed that both servers load the `org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor` class from the same `glassfish/modules/bean-validator-cdi.jar` package. All the classes involved in the stacktrace I tested are loaded from the same jars on both servers.

Comment: As you're getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor`, at least some class loader is not able to find that particular jar, or has found something else along the way that prevents it from finding that one (e.g. it found an older version of that jar that doesn't contain that class).

Comment: Sounds crazy, but this class is loaded only once on the working server, and only once on the failing one, from the very same package, containing the very same manifest and class files

Comment: beats me :-( without anything better to suggest, you could try getting the JRE versions identical, who knows.

Comment: unsurprinsingly, this does not fix it. I updated the original question with some more details. This is nonsense, I suspect some hardware issue now :/

Comment: If you could upload verbose output of both servers, up to the point where the one throws the exception, I will have a look.

Comment: Not much interesting in the log - the exact same output, and after the WELD warnings (present on both side), the exception is raised.